# Checking four-digits entries in a column by postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, digits

I have a table of user data in postgesql. And I have a certain knowledge of using four-digits combinations in the email address field by the spammers. For example, "john-smith-1974-mail@gmail.com" or "nansy.sin.2001@hotmail.com". Unfortunately, such four-digits combinations could be in any place of a email string. The task is to select by sql means only those rows of the table which contain such combinations. Please help. Maybe some kind of regexp can do the trick. And yes, I understand the danger of covering real people's email - I have good additional checking for that.

I tried dumb "LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'" checking but with no result. I expect selecting only those rows of the table which contain "DDDD" combinations in any place of the given field. If the answer is based on using some kind of function which finds exactly year-like entries - it will fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a POSIX regular expression match with the pattern `\d{4}`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE email ~ '\d{4}';
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim! The expression suggested by you did the trick. Actually, I did my homework and googled for a solution studiously but found nothing even close to your answer. Simple and brilliant. I'm new on this platform but if there is some legal way to send to you my gratitude, I would gladly do so.

Comment: You may buy me a coffee using the link from my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen

Comment: Your studious googling failed to find an entire chapter in the official docs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html